# How to Access Files inside moodledata folder in Moodle

Tags: image, file-upload, upload, moodle

I am new to moodle.  I created a file upload in plugin.  The file will be uploaded inside `/moodledata/logoimage`.  I don't know how to display the file in UI.

I tried to display like `/file.php/logoimage/logo1.jpg` in the browser.

It says Invalid Course Id.  If I access any image like `/file.php/7/logoimage/logo1.jpg` where 7 is the course ID the image works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite understand what you are trying to do and I don't think you want to store files in moodledata root, but the first thing you must pay attention to is that file management changed radically changed from version 1.9 to 2.x.

You should look for information in Moodle documentation (http://docs.moodle.org) and in the forums (http://moodle.org/forums/).

Moodle community forums are very active and I am sure you will get answers to your questions very quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply..  My questions is how to get an image which is inside moodledata/PDFImage/logo.jpg..

Comment: You must look into Moodle's File API Documentation.
You find it here: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API#Serving_files_to_users